# Chrome browser opens every time I run Protractor even after setting firefox as the browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, protractor, ui-automation

I have set the browserName as firefox in the config file.

[image]

And I start the selenium server: webdriver-manager --gecko start.
I have geckodriver version 0.26.0 and firefox version 65.
When I run protractor conf.js, it is still triggering Chrome.
I tried running the standalone server which is deprecated. i.e. selenium-standalone npm, it still triggers Chrome.
I also installed the latest protractor.
NodeJS : 10.21.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typo on `Capabilities`, should be lowercase `capabilities`.

Due to protractor can NOT find `capabilities`, so protractor give a default capabilities which use Chrome as browser.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at it.